# Calling an other batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have made a batch file that call another one `program.bat`, the first batch do its commands and then call the second one `program.bat` like this,

```
    @echo off
    bla bla bla
    ....
    ...
    ...
    call program.bat
```

But in this way, it will execute the second bat showing its output, however I want it to hide the `program.bat` output and show instead the phrase `please wait ...`and when `program.bat` finish his job, I want the first bat to return to do its other commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
echo Please wait ...
call program.bat >nul 2>&1
```

the `>nul` redirects standard output of `program.bat` to `nul` (to nothing), meaning it is not displayed. `2>&1` redirects other errors (yes, they are considered a different output) to the standard output, which is redirected to `nul`.